# Bootstrap columns not aligning in the same row

Tags: html, css, razor, bootstrap-4

Trying to render dynamically buttons and place 3 buttons in each row but they appear on the screen all in a separate row?

```
 <div class="row">
<div class="container sports-container col-md-12">

    @foreach (var sport in Model.Aggregator.SportsRepository.List().Where(x => x.ParentSportId == null))
    {
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info">@sport.Description</a>
        </div>
    }


</div>
```

```
<style>
.sports-container {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Is your browser width below the threshold for Bootstrap to responsively 'snap' medium columns?

Comment: @JonUleis I don't think so Jon.

Comment: I ask because the 3 buttons appear in a row fine on this JSFiddle if the pane is > 992px (which is Bootstrap's medium threshold): https://jsfiddle.net/um9krh1y/

Comment: @JonUleis Even on the Fiddle they appear in a separate row on my screen, what would be the alternative for this in my case?

Comment: Did you make the pane 992px or wider?

Comment: @JonUleis If i am looking at the right think it is 1583px

Answer (score 5):

From the [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/):

> - Containers provide a means to center your site’s contents. Use `.container` for fixed width or `.container-fluid` for full width.
> - Rows are horizontal groups of columns that ensure your columns are lined up properly. We use the negative margin method on .row to ensure all your content is aligned properly down the left side.
> - Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.

In other words, `div class='row'` needs to be inside `div class='container'` in your code.

```css
.sports-container {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M"
  crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container sports-container col-md-12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><a class="btn btn-outline-info">Baseball</a></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><a class="btn btn-outline-info">Hockey</a></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><a class="btn btn-outline-info">Tennis</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```